# How I can display data using wheredoesnthave

Tags: laravel

I have one problem.i have group table

[image]

This table has many to many relationship with users table and I have declared the relationship in both model.

And this is join table

[image]

Group.php

```
class Group extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps=true;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public function creators()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use HasApiTokens;
    use HasFactory;
    use HasProfilePhoto;
    use Notifiable;
    use TwoFactorAuthenticatable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public function grp()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }
}
```

[image]
This is the page where it will display the group that user have request
[image]
And supposedly in this page it will display the group that user have not request yet which is line no 3.

This is the code of my project.

**Controller**

```
public function redirectFunct(Request $request)
    {
        $role=Auth::user()->role;
        $userid=Auth::user()->id;

        if($role=='3')
        {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
            $groups=Group::with('creators');
           

              $exists = Group::whereDoesntHave('creators', function ($query) {
                    $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
                })->get();

                if($exists)
                {
                    $users=Join::where('userID', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
                }

            $request = Join::where('userApprove','=','0')->where('userID',$userid)->get();

           
           
            return view('member.dashboard',['users'=>$users,'user'=>$user,'groups'=>$groups,'exists'=>$exists,'request'=>$request]);
        }
```

**dasboard.blade.php**

```
//sugessted group tab
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sales" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sales-tab">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 stretch-card">
                              <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <li class="nav-item nav-search d-none d-lg-block w-100">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="search">
                                          <i class="mdi mdi-magnify"></i>
                                        </span>
                                      </div>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search now" aria-label="search" aria-describedby="search">
                                    </div>
                                  </li>
                                  <br>
                                  <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="" class="table">
                                      <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                          <th>No.</th>
                                          <th>Group Name</th>
                                          <th>Group Description</th>
                                          <th></th>
                                          <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                        @foreach($exists as $group)
                                        
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                                          <td>{{$group->groupName}}</td>
                                          <td>{{$group->groupDesc}}</td>
                                          <td>
                                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalCenter{{$group->id}}">Details</button>
                                          <!-- Modal -->
                                          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter{{$group->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                              <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Group Details</h5>
                                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                  </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                  <p>Group Name:{{$group->groupName}}</p>
                                                  <p>Group Description : {{$group->groupDesc}}</p>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                          </td>
                                          <td><a href="{{url('/join',$group->id)}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary .btn-{color}">Join</button></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        
                                        @endforeach
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
              //pending group tab
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="t" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="t-tab">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 stretch-card">
                              <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                  <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="" class="table">
                                      <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                          <th>No.</th>
                                          <th>Group Name</th>
                                          <th>Group Description</th>
                                          <th></th>
                                          <th></th>
                                        </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                        @foreach($request as $req)   
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                                          <td>{{$req->group->groupName}}</td>
                                          <td>{{$req->group->groupDesc}}</td>
                                          <td><a href ="{{url('/cancelrequest',$req->id)}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger .btn-{color}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Cancel</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I really appreciated if someone help me, please inform  if there is not enough information, I will  add it ASAP.

Comment: It seems unclear what your actual problem is? what are your challenges what is not showing as expected etc.?

Comment: 'suggested group' tab, expected output should only display group with id=3, because id=1 and id 2  user already request and display in 'pending group' tab.